# HTML select option VALUE calculate

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple "registry book" from a select HTML

The idea is 3 selecting options click confirm and based on the selected options make a price with a math formula or (don't know what is ) an array (in the sense of a table of like every var there) add a Hour:Minute from machine and place it in a paragraph.

It will work. (just learning HTML and CSS)
Math would be select2 * select3 with one exception in the case of [select2(option1 and option2) * select3 = samevalue)
With that aside can someone post a modular simplistic type of code that would Help.

For those who need to read some more:(copy&paste* - *Sorry for indentation)

```js
document.getElementById("Confirm").onClick = function() {
  var entry = ""

  document.getElementById("Televizor").onChange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex !== 0) {
      entry += this.value;
    }
  };

  document.getElementById("Controllere").onChange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex !== 0) {
      entry += this.value;
    }
  };

  document.getElementById("Timp").onChange = function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex !== 0) {
      entry += this.value;
    }
  };

  document.getElementById("Table").innerHTML = "<br> " + entry + Date();
  var entry = ""
}
```

```html
<h2>TV-uri</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">Date &amp; Time.</button>

<p id="demo">Dunno</p>

<div class="container">
  <select id="Televizoare">
    <option value="0">Televizoare</option>
    <option value="1">Tv 1</option>
    <option value="2">Tv 2</option>
    <option value="3">TV 3</option>
    <option value="4">Tv 4</option>
    <option value="5">TV 5</option>
    <option value="6">Tv 6</option>
    <option value="7">TV 7</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Controller">
    <option value="0">Controllere</option>
    <option value="1c">1 Controller</option>
    <option value="2c">2 Controllere</option>
    <option value="3c">3 Controllere</option>
    <option value="4c">4 Controllere</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Timp">
    <option value="0">Timp</option>
    <option value="1h">1 ora</option>
    <option value="1h2">1 ora 30 minute</option>
    <option value="2h">2 ore</option>
    <option value="2h2">2 ore 30 minute</option>
    <option value="3h">3 ore</option>
  </select>
  <button id="Confirm" onclick="Confrim)">Confirm</button>
</div>

<p id="Table"></p>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem you are having? Are you getting any errors? What is it you would like help with? Also, don't be sorry for properly indenting your code, that's what you should do. You do have some improperly written HTML, so you should start by correcting that. Copy your code to https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: my pic would make it clearer but i can't upload it since i'm new here.
in python chopped ways would be:
x= [] y=[] z=[]
if select1 value = 1  add string to var x .... do the same for select 2 and 3. if confirm pressed print x , print y where Y is the time HH:MM  , print z where Z would be the formula

Comment: Please edit your original question and include the code/comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could start off by making sure the spelling and capitalization of your IDs and function names match.

Also, you should create some form of a validation method to check if all the fields are valid before proceeding to the calculation method.

Not sure what you are multiplying, but if you can at least get the valuse from the form fields, that's half the battle.

You should also enclose all your fields within a form object so you can natively interact with the form in a traditional HTML fashion.

```js
// Define the confirm clicke listener for the Confirm button.
function confirm() {
  // Grab all the fields and apply them to a map.
  var fields = {
    'Televizoare' : document.getElementById('Televizoare'),
    'Controllere' : document.getElementById('Controllere'),
    'Timp'        : document.getElementById('Timp')
  };

  // Determine if the user selected an option for all fields.
  var isValid = doValidation(fields);
  if (!isValid) {
    document.getElementById("Table").innerHTML = 'Please provide all fields!';
    return;
  }

  // Create listeners ???
  fields["Televizoare"].onChange = function(e) { };
  fields["Controllere"].onChange = function(e) { };
  fields["Timp"].onChange        = function(e) { };

  // Set the value of the paragraph to the selected values.
  document.getElementById("Table").innerHTML = Object.keys(fields)
    .map(field => fields[field].value)
    .join(' &mdash; ');
}

// Validation function to check if ALL fields have options selected other than 0.
function doValidation(fields) {
  return [].every.call(Object.keys(fields), field => fields[field].selectedIndex !== 0);
}
```

```html
<h2>TV-uri</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">Date &amp; Time.</button>

<p id="demo">Dunno</p>

<div class="container">
  <select id="Televizoare">
    <option value="0">Televizoare</option>
    <option value="1">Tv 1</option>
    <option value="2">Tv 2</option>
    <option value="3">TV 3</option>
    <option value="4">Tv 4</option>
    <option value="5">TV 5</option>
    <option value="6">Tv 6</option>
    <option value="7">TV 7</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Controllere">
    <option value="0">Controllere</option>
    <option value="1c">1 Controllere</option>
    <option value="2c">2 Controllere</option>
    <option value="3c">3 Controllere</option>
    <option value="4c">4 Controllere</option>
  </select>
  <select id="Timp">
    <option value="0">Timp</option>
    <option value="1h">1 ora</option>
    <option value="1h2">1 ora 30 minute</option>
    <option value="2h">2 ore</option>
    <option value="2h2">2 ore 30 minute</option>
    <option value="3h">3 ore</option>
  </select>
  <button id="Confirm" onclick="confirm()">Confirm</button>
</div>

<p id="Table"></p>
```